# Why are the keys and values of a borrowed HashMap accessed by reference, not value?

Tags: collections, rust, ownership, borrowing

I have a function that takes a borrowed `HashMap` and I need to access values by keys. Why are the keys and values taken by reference, and not by value?

My simplified code:

```
fn print_found_so(ids: &Vec<i32>, file_ids: &HashMap<u16, String>) {
    for pos in ids {
        let whatever: u16 = *pos as u16;
        let last_string: &String = file_ids.get(&whatever).unwrap();

        println!("found: {:?}", last_string);
    }
}
```

- Why do I have to specify the key as a reference, i.e., `file_ids.get(&whatever).unwrap()` instead of `file_ids.get(whatever).unwrap()`?
- As I understand it, the `last_string` has to be of type `&String`, meaning a *borrowed string*, because the owning collection is borrowed. Is that right?
- Similar to the above point, am I correct in assuming `pos` is of type `&u16` because it takes borrowed values from `ids`?

Comment: Ok, got it. Comming from other dev world, this sometimes helped me to see the `&` sign more clearly..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Think about the semantics of passing parameters as references or as values:

- As reference: no ownership transfer. The called function merely borrows the parameter.
- As value: the called function takes ownership of the parameter and may not be used by the caller anymore.

Since the function `HashMap::get` does not need ownership of the key to find an element, the less restrictive passing method was chosen: by reference.

Also, it does not return the value of the element, only a reference. If it returned the value, the value inside the `HashMap` would no longer be owned by the `HashMap` and thus be inaccessible in the future.

Comment: In short: because it's cheapest.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. What confused me most, was the ` &whatever`. I would expect that simple u16 can be copied by value (and this might be even more performant than e.g. copying 64bit value as pointer).

Comment: @stej a `u16` **can** be copied by value. However, since a `HashMap` is generic, it was to be built to be useful to other types that aren't copyable. You can always copy / clone the reference to get a `u16` back if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Rust is not Java.

Rust may have high-level constructs, and data-structures, but it is at heart a low-level language, as illustrated by one of its guiding principle: *You don't pay for what you don't use*.

As a result, the language and its libraries will as much as possible attempt to eliminate any cost that is superfluous, such as allocating memory needlessly.

*Case 1: Taking the key by value.*

If the key is a `String`, this means allocating (and deallocating) memory for each and every look-up, when you could use a local buffer that is only allocated once and for all.

*Case 2: Returning by value.*

Returning by value means that either:

- you remove the entry from the container to give it to the user
- you copy the entry in the container to give it to the user

The latter is obviously inefficient (copy means allocation), the former means that if the user wants the value back in another insertion has to take place again, which means look-up etc... and is also inefficient.

In short, returning by value is inefficient in this case.

Rust, therefore, takes the most logical choice as far as efficiency is concerned and passes and returns by value whenever practical.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read about ownership more times, but sometimes it doesn't click in my head ;) And then more info is useful.

Answer (score 3):

While it seems unhelpful when the key is a `u16`, think about how it would work with a more complex key such as a `String`.

In that case taking the key by value would often mean having to allocate and initialise a new `String` for each lookup, which would be expensive.